# Can you craft magic firearms with Craft Magic Arms and Armor without the gun-smithing feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you craft magic firearms with Craft Magic Arms and Armor without the gun-smithing feat?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question correctly, so... Craft Magic Arms and Armor does not craft firearms, or weapons, or armors. It makes existing masterwork weapon/armor magical. Are you asking if you must have crafted the weapon yourself?

Comment: Technically both. But my reasoning will be another question and that's a "no no" in the comment section and I'm already on the watch list. However it has something to do with the difference between putting buffs on your gear magically but temporarily vs a permanent buffs.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver What watch list?  As written, there seems to be some elements of the question missing, though it appears that someone was able to sort out your key needs in an answer.

Comment: @Korvin Jhyarelle Silver has been told repeatedly to not use comments to ask follow-up questions. Based on these comments, I think it's still not understood why that's a problem…

Comment: Jhyarelle, you can clarify your question's reasoning in comments, just not ask **new** ones after you've got an answer. Although, you don't even need to use comments in this case: you could just put your whole question into the question instead.

Comment: Have you asked the second question as well? If so, it might be worth linking the two to each other as related.  @SevenSidedDie Ah, sorry, was unaware.

Comment: <comment deleted> Please use civil language when using the site. (Specifically, don't curse at people.) If you are confused about what comments can and can't be used for, or have questions about previous mod instructions to you, I encourage you to ask a question about it on [meta].

Comment: What? Why? When? Who? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

You don't need the gunsmithing feat to do anything besides repair and restore the initial weapon you got as a gunslinger (if you have one).  All other items the gunsmithing feat lets you craft you could already craft normally.  Gunsmithing just bypasses the skill checks involved and gives you the option to make 400 gp/day from sale of ammunition (or you can keep some of that ammunition for yourself).

Comment: As a DM there is no way I would let you "make 400 gp/day from sale of ammunition". The purpose of crafting cheap ammunitions is to make the class playable without having to spend fortunes on munitions, not to break the WBL on your knees.

Comment: @annoyingimp better?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Ok, but that's what the feat's for, as written.  It isn't actually that great though; it costs a feat unless you're a gunslinger and they're a pretty low-tier class.  It's excellent at very low levels, but it isn't long til rogue stuff or spellcaster stuff outpaces it.  To each their own, I suppose.